# How to handle syncing a user's db with a master db on a server?

Tags: iphone, database, database-design

So I'm planning an app that will involve having a master db on a server, lets say 3,000 CDs, with the columns Title, Artist, and Release Date.

1)When a user adds a CD to their collection, it will add it to the apps local SQLite DB. But lets say I spelled a CD title wrong, so I make an update to it. When the user goes to sync, how should I go about handling an updated row? Should I have a column 'IsUpdated' that is just a numeric value that increase by one every time I update that row? That way when the app sees IsUpdated on the server is larger than the local IsUpdated for that particular item, it will now to replace the contents. Does that make sense? Is it even practical? What other option would there be?

2) How would I do about handling the addition of brand new columns? Like adding a Barcode or Price? Do I just push an update for the app that adds the new columns locally, then do the same on the server, and let the rest take its run? Which would also trickle to number 1 with the syncing issue.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to give more detail than that. Is the entire 3000 master list also replicated down to the remote db?

Sounds like it.

Ok so if that the case, this isn't a DB design issue so much as it is replication.

It's a bad idea to update every row in a table, especially one that makes the row longer. You'll be better off just dropping the table and recreating. <--- that's how it works in RDBMS  on servers, no idea if that concept changes on a client db. And now we get into more iPhone questions of replication than simple db replication. Would it be better to just republish the app? Is the user data segregated from the server data. Can DDL be done on the local/remote tables after published?

Instead of searching the entire list for changes as you outline in #1. I would keep a dated delta table. The local app would store a last_updated_Datetime, any records in the delta table after that datetime would need to be brought down. Once downloaded the local system can determine how to apply them. Again this is inappropriate for mass changes.